# Reconstruct a vector with a known vector and residual

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I observe $\vec y \in \mathcal R^n$ and know $\vec x$. I assume that $\vec y$ mostly consists of $\vec x$, with some added residual $\vec r$.

This gives me the problem $\vec y = a\vec x + \vec r$, where $a \in [0, 1]$. Furthermore, I assume that we should maximize $a$. Otherwise, $a = 0, \vec r = \vec y$ would be a trivial solution.

Another way to express the problem for $\mathcal R^3$ would be:

$\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 & r_1 \\
0 & a & 0 & r_2 \\
0 & 0 & a & r_3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}$

In this version, matrix elements would need to be calculated, but we need to do it in a way that maximizes $a$.

How to best approach this problem?